# Eclipse Neon eGit Integration gives Exception 401 Authorization Required

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, eclipse-neon

After upgrading to Neon my Egit integration has failed with the following Exception

[image]

UPDATE: [See eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000)

> i.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/[REPOSITORY]/SCA: 401
>   Authorization Required    at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:169)   at
>   org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PushOperation.run(PushOperation.java:217)    at
>   org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.PushOperationUI.execute(PushOperationUI.java:167)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.PushOperationUI$1.run(PushOperationUI.java:229)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused
>   by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException:
>   https://github.com/SCASoftware/SCA: 401 Authorization Required    at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$Service.openResponse(TransportHttp.java:855)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$MultiRequestService.execute(TransportHttp.java:956)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$Service$HttpExecuteStream.read(TransportHttp.java:882)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.UnionInputStream.read(UnionInputStream.java:145)
>     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:112)
>     at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:247)  at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.needDataPacket(SideBandInputStream.java:154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.read(SideBandInputStream.java:136)
>     at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:247)  at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readString(PacketLineIn.java:138)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.readStringLongTimeout(BasePackPushConnection.java:395)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.readStatusReport(BasePackPushConnection.java:328)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.doPush(BasePackPushConnection.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpPushConnection.doPush(TransportHttp.java:786)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.push(BasePackPushConnection.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:167)
>     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1250)   at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:158)   ... 4
>   more

I have chequed my credentials in gitHub web interface and keeps failing. More information:

> eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200 
>   java.version=1.8.0_101
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation 
>   BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES Framework 
>   arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product 
>   Command-line arguments:  -os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Hemendra Sharma. The only solution I have is listed below

Comment: what if i am trying to clone a new repo and getting this error? :(

Comment: I assume that you can A) use the command line B) Use an older version  to clone it:(

Comment: Found the solution. Please check my answer below. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short version**. It is a Eclipse bug. The new version that fixes the problem is available by doing:

- Help -> Install New Software
- Work with: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.5.1a
- Select the "EPP Marketplace Client"
- Proceed with defaults

**Long version**: I was only trying to clone. But one subtle behavior I noticed, and that's perhaps a workaround for everyone, is that when you see a prompt for the password (the prompt without the check box to save it and without your user ID prefilled in the dialog), it's really MPC that's prompting for the password. If you enter a valid password, then EGit will not see a 401 response code, so EGit will not fill in your saved password when communicating with that server, hence the next EGit/JGit access will result in a 401 because the saved credentials are not being used. The tricky thing I noticed was that if I just hit escape or pressed cancel on the bogus password prompt, then EGit starts to work.

There is a discussion in the Eclipse Forum: [Eclipse Community Forum - Reply](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1081631&goto=1744755&#msg_1744755) and a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000).

Comment: Edited to make the solution more evident without the need to read the whole forum and bug. But certainly solves de problem

Comment: Just wow... This is one of these errors, where one can look for the root of it for ages. Thanks for your eagle eye and sharing!

Answer (score 0):

This workarround is a suboptimal solution but at least worked for me. I had the old workspace with the old Eclipse Marte version. I tried to set the same credentials in the same way and unsurprisingly the old eclipse worked. But it also warned me that other application had modified the password store and asked me to changed them. Modifing it with the old eclipse made the Neon work. They seem to share the password store at least in Windows.

[image]